# How can i pass a form or url parameters to a modal popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-parameters, modalpopup

I am working on page that open a modal popup to retrieve data from the database. But when i click on submit button, the modal popup come up perfectly but it does one retrieve the info from database.
Please can someone help me modify the form so that it would retrieve a url parameter when the modal popup is clicked.

**Here is the form:**
I got it from [here](https://codepen.io/hanapiers/embed/EXNrGP?default-tab=html%2Cresult&embed-version=2&height=191&pen-title=Bootstrap%20Modal%20on%20Form%20Submit&slug-hash=EXNrGP&theme-id=dark&user=hanapiers&name=cp_embed_1#html-box)

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="openModal()" id="myForm">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="submit">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe by storing the param's value in a global variable

Comment: What is your database ? If it is RESTful API, i think you can fetch it easily.

Comment: Before showing the modal do an ajax request, get your data, on ajax success event change modal content, than raise your modal. One more thing, remove your form `onsubmit` attribute, because you control it via `$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) { ... }`